# Implementing HTML/CSS menu in WordPress theme

Tags: theme-development

I have an HTML/CSS template having a horizontal menu. I need to convert the template into a WordPress theme. I am stuck with the menu. I have used the wp_nav_menu function in my header.php file and have also completed the functions.php file. The menu is now displaying vertically with bullets. I need to implement the menu now, but am unable to find and associate the proper css class to the menu_class parameter. Kindly assist.

Thanks and Regards

Debashis

Answer (score 1):

Just look at [`wp_nav_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) arguments:

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

You can use `menu_id` argument to set its `id` attribute and `menu_class` to set its class attribute. You can set containers id/class attributes as well.